# Help in creating a card stack

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to develop a card game with Flex, and I was wondering if there's a way to create an horizontal list (the cards that I have in my hand) having the elements overlapped, like you can see in this example made with openflux:

http://www.ryancampbell.com/flex/StackListExample/StackListExample.html

the thing that's missing here is the possibility to swap the cards with drag and drop.
Any ideas on what I could do to get a similar effect with an horizontallist based component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Flex 4, its a pretty straightforward custom layout.

some links to get you started.

[RIA](http://insideria.com/2009/05/flex-4-custom-layouts.html)

[Adobe TV](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/flash-camp-boston/creating-custom-layouts-in-flex-4-/)

Comment: wow, pretty amazing.. unfortunately I'm still using Flex 3, but I guess I could start finally using Flex 4.

Comment: I had a look at Flex 4 but I don't think I'm ready to make that step :D I think I'll stay with Flex 3 as it is for now..I've been using it only for a year..

Answer (score 0):

Yo

I was looking at a 3D layout the other day for Five3D (an opensource 3d api), and saw an example of a Card game/layout that may give you some inspiration:

http://www.danielenstrom.com/solitaire/

Comment: Wow, that's mind blowing :P but maybe it's kinda complex for a multiplayer game.. and I guess it was made with Flash, I wanted to keep the clean structure of a Flex RIA.